# hadoop streaming jobs fails to report?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

All jobs were running successfully using hadoop-streaming, but all of a sudden I started to see errors due to one of worker machines

```
Hadoop job_201110302152_0002 failures on master

Attempt Task    Machine State   Error   Logs
attempt_201110302152_0002_m_000037_0    task_201110302152_0002_m_000037 worker2 FAILED  
Task attempt_201110302152_0002_m_000037_0 failed to report status for 622 seconds. Killing!
-------
Task attempt_201110302152_0002_m_000037_0 failed to report status for 601 seconds. Killing!
Last 4KB
Last 8KB
All
```

**Questions :**

```
- Why does this happening ?  
- How can I handle such issues?
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The description for [mapred.task.timeout](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/mapred-default.html) which defaults to 600s says "The number of milliseconds before a task will be terminated if it neither reads an input, writes an output, nor updates its status string. "

Increasing the value of mapred.task.timeout might solve the problem, but you need to figure out if more than 600s is actually required for the map task to complete processing the input data or if there is a bug in the code which needs to be debugged.

According to the Hadoop best practices, on average a map task should take a minute or so to process an InputSplit.

Comment: Thanks Praveen, i'll check that out and let you know